# Google static maps api issue- won't display all my markers

Tags: django, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I have a project where I need to automatically generate maps with markers. I have successfully generated these maps with the built-in markers and now watch to switch to custom markers to more accurately describe the items being marked.

So far I have been able to do this fine for 2-3 icons, but as soon as I add more (say 5/6 icons) some of them are simply omitted from the map. Currently these images are all hosted on the same machine running the code and are served up via my Django website.

My first thought is that the issue has to do with my server being too slow to serve up all 6 icons simultaneously in the time google takes to render the static map, but I would think that google's code waits for the marker icons to load before rendering.....

Any suggestions? I would post my request here, but I don't want to publish my API key. If you think it would be helpful, I could post an obfuscated version.

Answer (score 1):

After additional research, it appears there is a limit of 5 custom markers per staticmaps api request.

To get around this, make multiple requests and merge the maps. For maps 2+ set the maptype to roadmap and style=feature:all|visibility:off

More details can be found here: [Anyway to overcome the 5 custom icon urls per request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893945/anyway-to-overcome-the-5-custom-icon-urls-per-request)